# Как заставить циклы искать одинаковые символы?

Tags: python

Даны две строки. Создать строку, состоящую только из символов, общих для двух данных строк. 
Я могу заставить искать схожести в s1[0] и s2[0]. А если похожие символы в двух разных строках? Помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Самый простой и притом эффективный способ - это воспользоваться пересечением [множеств](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset):

```
a = 'abcde'
b = 'cdefg'

c = ''.join(set(a) & set(b))
```